# Setting proper python setup script

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, distutils

I have a huge problem to create proper python setup script. My folder structure looks like this:

```
my_project/
    my_project/
        --__init__.py
        --file_1.py
        --file_2.py
        --file_3.py
    -AUTHORS
    -CHANGELOG
    -INSTALL
    -LICENSE
    -README.rst
    -setup.cfg
    -setup.py
```

I have created a setup script, but it does not behave like I want to. The setup script:

```
from ez_setup import use_setuptools
use_setuptools()
import os
import sys
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
readme_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'README.rst')
try:
    long_description = open(readme_file).read()
except IOError, err:
    sys.stderr.write("[ERROR] Cannot find file specified as ""``long_description`` (%s)\n" % readme_file)
    sys.exit(1)
setup(
    name = 'my_project',
    version='0.0.1',
    author = 'AUTHOR',
    author_email = 'CONTACT',
    url = 'http://example.com',
    description= 'Some description',
    long_description = long_description,
    packages = find_packages('my_project'),
    package_dir = {'':'my_project'},
        package_data = {'':['*.py']},
    include_package_data = True,
    scripts = [],
    requires = [],
    license = 'BSD License',
    install_requires = [
        'some_packages',
    ],
    classifiers = [
        'Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha',
        'Environment :: Web Environment',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Topic :: Database',
        'Topic :: Internet',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
    ],
    keywords = 'python, setup, script, the best',
)
```

After this:

```
sudo python setup.py alias release register sdist bdist_egg upload
sudo python setup.py release
```

Everything is fine, up to this point, but when I try:

```
sudo pip install my_project
```

I only get in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ a folder called my_project-0.0.1.egg-info/, but there are no my_project with **init**, file_1, file_2, file_3 python files.

I know that my_project-0.0.1.egg-info/ is required, but where are my files?

Then I tried:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

With no effect, but this time I got a folder my_project-0.0.1-py2.7.egg.

I want to get in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ two directories:

```
- my_project-0.0.1.egg-info/
- my_project with my files
```

## My questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I resolve it?
3. Maybe when I try to use
   distutils instead of setuptools it can help me?

Comment: First, you probably don't want to use `ez_setup` with modern `setuptools` (post-`distribute` merge). What version do you have? And have you tried it with just the first two lines removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
package_dir = {'':'my_project'},
```

You're telling it that `my_project` is the place to find top-level packages. So, `find_packages('my_project')` is going to look for a package inside your top-level directory (`my_project`) at `my_project/my_project`. Since there is no such thing, you end up with an empty package.

Just remove that line, and everything will work.

---

While we're at it, you're over-complicating things a little bit. You're not using anything out of `ez_setup`, so it would be simpler to remove the first two lines. And you're just adding a single static package, so there's really no reason to use `find_packages`; you can just use `packages = ['my_project']` instead.

---

Meanwhile, here's how to debug stuff yourself in the future.

First, don't try `sudo python setup.py alias release register sdist bdist_egg upload` until you've actually got things working. It's a lot easier to debug local files than something you've already uploaded to PyPI. Just do `python setup.py sdist`, then you can look at the resulting tarball and make sure it looks OK, then try `pip install .` and/or `pip install dist/my_project-0.0.1.tar.gz` to make sure it actually works.

Second, `setup.py` is just normal Python code; you can always log things to see what's going on. For example, if `find_packages('my_project')` doesn't seem to be working right, try doing a `print(find_packages('my_project'))` before the `setup(…)` to see what it's doing.